# why do i get 'none' when i write a variable to textfile

Tags: python, text-files, nonetype

the problem that is occurring in my code is that any variable 
(in this case time and option_1 ) written to a textfile outputs ' none ' as an outcome in the actual textfile.

```
time=print ("This is the time and date: " 
,datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H-%M"))
option_1=print("50p for 1 hour(S) stay")  
with open("recipt.txt", "w") as recipt:
     recipt.write("you time\n {}".format(time))
     recipt.write("the time you stayed for and your payment\n 
{}".format(option_1))
     recipt.close()
```

thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a syntax error, you can't have a line break in a string unless you use triple-quotes.

Comment: remove the `print`

Comment: `print` doesn't return anything, so assigning the results of `print` to `time` and `option_1` will give you `None`

Comment: you don't need the print statements just write `time = "This is the time and date: " 
,datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H-%M")`

Comment: im so sorry, my strings don't actually have a line break, i couldn't copy it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print` function returns `None`. You want to build a `str` object rather than use `print`.

```
time= "This is the time and date: " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
option_1= "50p for 1 hour(S) stay"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
time=print ("This is the time and date: ")
```

In Python, every function returns a value. If a value is not specified, *None* is returned. The print function does not specify a return value, therefore it returns *None*. In your example, you are assigning the return value of print (which is *None*) to the time variable. Instead, set time equal to the current datetime.

```
time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
```

Then concatenate your print statement, and the current datetime.

```
print("This is the time and date: " + time)
```